# Console hanging when deleting Job in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to delete a Job in Kubernetes, but every time I run "kubectl delete job [JOBNAME]" it just "hangs" indefinitely.

How can I diagnose this issue to try and determine why the Job's not able to be deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn up your debugging by set the verbosity to 9. You will see that `kubectl` is actually clearing out a lot of different resources created by the job. `ctrl-c` out of it.

Use `--cascade=false` it will actually complete shortly. see [issue 8598](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/8598#issuecomment-104078236)